# Ignore specific field Update to Solr Document

Tags: java, json, solr

I am currently using Solr 5.1 and facing error that I don't want to update date field in my document. I am update document to solr using HTTP connection. Below URL is how I update to solr..

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/update?commit=true
```

When I update document everything is update. I don't want to update date field in my document. I try to use atomic update but it not work they way what I want. Here is example how I update document,

```
[
{
    "id": "http://myitmakhamediagroup.com/test/json/test/234", 
    "content": {"set": "blah blah blah"},
    "data": {"set": "blahblahblah"},
    "timestamp":"2016-12-19T15:44:46Z"
}
]
```

This is how I update exiting document to Solr, I didn't put set field at the time stamp but it also update. I am no idea how to do it.

Is there any one give me suggestion how to ignore update for specific field from solr index document or should I need change in solr schema for not update time stamp specific field?

Answer (score 0):

Don't send the timestamp if you don't want to update it :

```
[
{
    "id": "http://myitmakhamediagroup.com/test/json/test/234", 
    "content": {"set": "blah blah blah"},
    "data": {"set": "blahblahblah"}
}
]
```